# facebook Log-in to web app considered as Facebook app or not?

Tags: admob, facebook-apps, passport.js

I'm a newbie. I would like to develop a web-app and I want my user to log-in using their Facebook account using this http://passportjs.org

in my web app I want to use google admob

but I have read this article: http://mashable.com/2007/07/26/money-making-facebook/ it says "It is not feasible to use Google Adsense for this since Facebook does not allow JavaScript embedding. Adsense may be embedded through iFrames, which despite being popular among Facebook developers, is against Google’s TOS."

When I use log-in with Facebook, is my app considered as Facebook app, or is it not i.e. it is just a web-app with Facebook login?

There might be some difference between these two cases because if I want to develop an app that will be use on the Facebook web page I need `HTTPS` for my server but if I use only log-in there is no need for `HTTPS`. So, I'm confuse what is considered a Facebook app and what is not?

In my case I only need <kbd>Facebook login</kbd> and <kbd>post to Facebook</kbd> function. Can I use google admob with my app or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Facebook apps are something completely different, they are embedded directly into Facebook pages. Facebook dictates here what an app can do and what it cannot. In particular, a Facebook app indeed cannot run JavaScript because that JavaScript would execute in the context of facebook.com. Consequently, using Adsense is impossible.

Your application however is a regular web application that is available under your URL, not Facebook's. Facebook login or a Facebook "like" button don't change that, you can still run any JavaScript code meaning that you can use Adsense.